# Column calculation based on formula from another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, formula

For example, suppose we have a table, which contains id of a formula and a formula itself. Second table would have id of a value and values themselves, which are to be used in the formulas.

So, there is a table, which connects formulas and values, like a template of a formula. For example, result of formula #1 is to be calculated from values #5, #16 and #228.

The thing is: each formula uses different values and different number of them and in different ways, BUT the same value can be used in different formulas. For example, formula #1 is calculated as #228 - #16 * #5, yet formula #2 is calculated as #16 * #228 + #356.

Which begs the question, is there a way to make a caluculated column based on a select statement and a predefined formula? Formulas will be written in the database by hand, not generated, so a formula can be based on value IDS.

I haven't yet chosen a DB engine for my project, as I am curious is there any engine which supports this kind of stuff at all?

I know a little something-something in the database world, yet I'm lacking expertise, so I would like to ask the more experienced programmers in this field.

Comment: You might take a look at prepared statements, but really I think you can ask a more concise question

Comment: Your question is very vague, and isn't related to databases, in fact.

Comment: In a well-structured database, it's hard to imagine that this could be useful

Comment: @AlexeySoshin
Well, this database is tied on dynamic data coming in in form of Events. Each event has an unknown number of attributes, but those attributes have predefined types. And there are formulas for each set of attribute types, but those formulas use each set differently.
The amount of data is large. The main goal is for each Event find a result of each possible Formula and write it to a temporary table.
Is this a bad structure, or it's not simply possible in a database and the calculations will have to be outside the database?

Comment: @Strawberry please, see my comment below.

Comment: There is no such thing as "value #16" in a row of a relational database table. Values are refenced by column names. If you specify the formulas based on column names of the table and the formula can be expressed as a valid SQL expression, then you can write a function in Postgres to evaluate the formula by passing the row and the formula (string) into it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what I meant by value #16 is the value of ID column in the Values table. In the Formulas table I would like to write the formula for a bunch of Values. Formula would have an ID column and an expression column. For example, (1, '$3 + $6 - $1').  Table ValuesInFormulas would have FormulaID and ValueID, so that I can specify which value ids are used in a formula. Lastly there are values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear on how you are going to find the actual formula and input parameters. But you can write a PL/pgSQL function that evaluates a given input string as a SQL expression:

```
create function eval(p_formula text, variadic parameters numeric[])
  returns numeric
as
$$
declare
  l_result numeric;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for idx  in 1..cardinality(parameters)  loop
    p_formula := replace(p_formula, concat('$', idx), parameters[idx]::text);
  end loop;
  execute 'select '||p_formula
     into l_result;
  return l_result;
end;  
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then `select eval('$1 * $2 + $3', 3, 4, 5)` returns 17

The above function is however not lenient about parameters not being passed. With the formula `$3 + $6 - $1` you have to pass at least 6 parameters, otherwise it would throw an error.